# cant find my viewmodel to create a new strongly typed view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

i have a view model that combines user data, and person data, i need to create a view for this vm, but when i go to create new vuew, chk strongly typed, and serch for my view model i cant find it

this is what i have:

```
HMSW
    > HMSDB (models project, contains 2 EF models)

    > HMSW (mvc4 project)
         > ViewModels
              > vm_usuario_nombre (my viewmodel)
```

view model code:

```
namespace HMSW.ViewModels
{
    class vm_usuario_seleccionado
    {

        public Users hmsUser { get; set; }
        public v_natural_person_short userNaturalPerson { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the class `public` or `internal` - just not `private`, which it currently is.

```
public class vm_usuario_seleccionado
```